# A Problem on Geometric Progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a_1,a_2,...$ be in G.P. where $a_1 = a$ and common ratio $r$ are
>   positive integers.
>
> If $\log_8 a_1 + \log_8 a_2 + ... + \log_8 a_{12} = 2014$, the the
>   number of order pairs $(a,r)$ is
>
> (A) **44** (B) **45** (C) **46** (D) **47**

I have tried the following but could not continue further.

$$\log_8 a_1 + \log_8 a_2 + ... + \log_8 a_{12} = 2014$$
$$ \Rightarrow \log_8 (a_1 *a_2 * ...*a_{12} ) = 2014$$
$$ \Rightarrow \log_8 (a^{12}*r^{1+2+...+11}) = 2014$$
$$ \Rightarrow \log_8 (a^{12}*r^{66}) = 2014$$
$$ \Rightarrow 12 \log_8 a + 66 \log_8 r = 2014$$
$$ \Rightarrow 3 (2 \log_8 a + 11 \log_8 r) = 1007$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\log_8(a_1) + \log_8(a_2)$?

Comment: If you're using the convention that $a_n = a r^n$, then in the third line you should have in the exponent of $r$ the sum up to and including $12$.  This change has a cascading effect on the remainder of the calculation.

Comment: No I am not using such convention because $a_1 = a$ as stated in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: from $ \log_8 (a^{12}*r^{66}) = 2014$, it follows that $8^{2014} = a^{12}. r^{66}$, so $2^{2014} = a^{4}. r^{22}$. Given the fact that $a$ and $r$ are positive integers, can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I did.

$$2^{1007} = a^2*r^{11}$$
Now let $a = 2^x$ and $r = 2^y$. This implies that $2x + 11y = 1007$. There are 45 positive integers less than 1007 which is even and divisible by 11. Thus, my answer is 45.

Comment: Yes, this implies that both $a$ and $r$ must be a power of 2, so ...

Comment: Anirban, well done, you got it!

Comment: Hm, slight detail, I count 46 pairs (x,y): (3,91), (14,89), (25,87), ... (493,1)